# How do I pull information from a database depending on a drop-down menu result

Tags: php, sql, database, drop-down-menu

I have simply pulled different gyms in from the database using SQL queries and now have to pull them in depending on the drop-down result. Here is what I have so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php 

require_once('connect.php'); //connecting to my database

mysql_select_db("gyms", $connect);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gym WHERE id='1'"); //each gym has an "id" field of 1-5

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['name']; //all different attributes in the gym database
echo $row['type'];
echo $row['price'];
echo $row['hours'];
echo $row['parking'];
echo $row['facilities'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown field needs to be part of a form.

```
if (!isset($_POST['gyms'])) {
echo '<form action="same.php" method="post">
    <select name="gyms">
        <option value="1">Gym 1</option>
        <option value="2">Gym 2</option>
    </select>
</form>';
} else {

    $id = $_POST['gyms'];
    // DO NOT forget to sanitize the value of $id before plugging it in
    // NEVER trust user input. Always assume it's a hacker.
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gym WHERE id=$id");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
    // $row should contain the results from the database for the given gym
    var_dump($row);
}
```

By the way, I highly suggest using PDO instead of the mysql_*() functions. Here are a few related links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: this is returning no output for some reason..i says that "$id = $_POST['gyms'];" has an undefined index?

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to access the index before the form is submitted. In other words, wrap the PHP from `$id = $_POST['gyms'];` down through the assignment of your variables from the database results in an if statement like `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: I have updated my question with a more complete code example. If you want to always show the drop down even after a gym has been selected, you can move the if() part down to where the else is (remove the else) and remove the negation of the isset() call. Also, note the comment at the end about PDO.